# Where to place the Google Sitelinks Search Box script?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working to optimize the load time of one of my websites. Recently, the test on GTMetrix revealed that I need to optimize the order of my scripts and stylesheets:

"The following inline script blocks were found in http://www.1to1french.com/ between an external CSS file and another resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS file, or after the next resource."

I found out that the inline script is Google Sitelinks Search Box. My question is can I move it somewhere to the end of the body tag or should I put it at the top?

Thanks in Advance